# Maven goal to append lines to file

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers

The context is that before compile, there is a goal to download a .proto (Google Protobuffer) file to have generated files after. In this proto file there is no package mentioned and so when the classes get generated they do not appear to any correct package so can't be imported and used.

A proto file here may be considered as a simple text file. I have a very specific need - I want to add some text at the beginning of this file.

Is it possible to do using maven?

Thank you.

Comment: It's possible to do that. But process in simple text file is more simple than a photo.

Comment: Are there any plugins to do that? Why are you talking about a photo?

Comment: I suspect he misread "proto" as "photo".

Comment: Yup, sorry. I misread the proto as photo. @astrohome You can try to find in maven repo, I think it may have some plugin to do that, if not you can use maven ant, then run the ant script to append text to your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nashorn-maven-plugin`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.github.michaldo</groupId>
            <artifactId>nashorn-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <script>
                            var Files = Java.type('java.nio.file.Files');
                            var Paths = Java.type('java.nio.file.Paths');
                            var content = new java.lang.String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get($basedir+ '/a.txt')));
                            content = "From nashorn with love\n" + content;
                            Files.write(Paths.get($basedir + '/a.txt'),
                            content.getBytes());
                        </script>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>eval</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

            </executions>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```